# cant compare two files. while loopsdont work

Tags: java, while-loop

EDIT:

i have to files, FileOne and FileTwo, which in every line there is a word or more. and i want to compare these two file, and see if every line of fileOne is exact the same or piece of a line of FileTwo. I made the code below with your ideas, but i my result is to small that means that it is not ckecking all the lines of fileOne. The code below, isn't going to the next object of it1?

```
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    ArrayList <String> File1 = File2List(FileOne);
    Iterator it1 = File1.listIterator();
    ArrayList <String> File2 = File2List(FileTwo);
    Iterator it2 = File2.listIterator();

    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        String outer = it1.next().toString();
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            String inner = it2.next().toString();
            index1 = outer.indexOf(inner);
            if(index1 != -1) { //Or compareIgnoreCase
                index2++;
                it1.next();
                break;
            }

        }
        it1.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Result: "+ index2);
```

Comment: To start with, reading in the *whole* of the second file for each line of the first file is incredibly inefficient. Load it into a `List<String>` to start with, then look over that list for each line of file 1. Now, you haven't said *in what way* it isn't working. What's it doing compared with what you want it do do?

Answer (score 1):

First (before offering the solution to the actual issue):

```
index1 = check.indexOf(toCheck);
if(index1 != -1){
    index2++;
    break; //mass1;
}
```

by

```
if(check.equals(checkTo)) { //Or equalsIgnoreCase
    index2++;
    break;
}
```

Because the line `Same start` and `Same start, diff end` are certainly not the same.

Actual issue:
You're reading the whole contents of file2 at each line of file1.

### Possible solution

1. Read the contents of file1 (line by line), and store it in an `ArrayList File1`
2. Read the contents of file2 (line by line), and store it in another `ArrayList File2`.
3. Compare the size of these ArrayLists with each other
4. If the're not equal, return (the files are definitely different).
5. Else, loop through each element of `ArrayList File1`, and compare using the previously described function to `ArrayList File2`.

Comment: You're still comparing the **whole** contents of `File2` with each line of `File1`. Have you actually read the guide at the bottom of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are one line from file one with every line from file two. That does not work. You have to get the next lines from file one in the second loop.

Example:

```
while (it1.hasNext()) {
    String outer = it1.next().toString();

    if(!it2.hasNext()) {
        // FALSE!
    } else {
        String inner = it2.next().toString();
        if(!inner.compare(outer)) { //Or compareIgnoreCase
            // FALSE
        }


    }
}

if(it2.hasNext()) {
    // FALSE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
package so7625322;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FindWords {

  private static List<String> loadLines(String fname) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fname);
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
      String line;
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
      }
      return lines;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  private boolean contains(Iterable<String> haystack, String needle) {
    for (String s : haystack) {
      if (s.contains(needle)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public boolean containsAll() throws IOException {
    List<String> words = loadLines("./NetBeansProjects/StemmerListComp/StemmedUnTunedQueries.txt");
    List<String> tocheck = loadLines("words-to-check");

    for (String s : tocheck) {
      if (!contains(words, s)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Some remarks:

- I have split the task into several small tasks, so that the main method `containsAll` looks as similar to your requirement as possible.
- Using the `loadLines` helper method the code also becomes simpler, since you don't need to be concerned about closing the files in the `containsAll` method anymore.

Comment: in that case you check every word, if it is same or part of "words-to-check". right? or if every "words-to-check" is same or part of word? thanks for your help anyway...

Comment: It's the latter. The code checks if every *words-to-check* is the same or a part of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This method will do the work.

```
private bool IsIdentical(string filePath1, string filePath2)
    {
        int file1Byte, file2Byte;
        FileStream fileStream1, fileStream2;

        //Open a stream to both files
        fileStream1 = new FileStream(filePath1, FileMode.Open);
        fileStream2 = new FileStream(filePath2, FileMode.Open);

        // Check the file sizes to determine if the files are identical.
        if (fileStream1.Length != fileStream2.Length)
        {
            fileStream1.Close();
            fileStream2.Close();
            return false;
        }

        //Read one byte from each file and compare them until either a non-matching 
        //set of bytes is found or until the end of the file.
        do
        {
            // Read one byte from each file.
            file1Byte = fileStream1.ReadByte();
            file2Byte = fileStream2.ReadByte();
        }
        while ((file1Byte == file2Byte) && (file1Byte != -1));

        fileStream1.Close();
        fileStream2.Close();

        return ((file1Byte - file2Byte) == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you not only want to check is all the line sin file1 against file2 but also determine the line where they differ.

```
List<String> file1 = File2List(fileOne);
List<String> file2 = File2List(fileTwo);
for(int i=0;i<file1.size() && i<file2.size();i++)
    if(!file2.get(i).contains(file1.get(i))) {
        System.out.println("mismatch at line "+i);
        return;
    }
if (file1.size()<file2.size()) {
    System.out.println("file1 is shorter than file2");
    return;
}
if (file2.size()<file1.size()) {
    System.out.println("file2 is shorter than file1");
    return;
}
System.out.println("no mismatches found");
```